# Prós e contras de garantir o contrato de uma interface por meio de uma subclasse

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, testes-de-unidade, interface, engenharia-de-software

[Este artigo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2004/10/24/api-design-myth-interface-as-contract/) apresenta uma interface `IList<T>` contendo os métodos `Add(T item)` e `Count()`. O contrato dessa interface espera que quando um item for adicionado, o método `Count()` reflita a nova quantidade de itens na lista. Isso pode inclusive ser definido na documentação da interface (uma pós-condição do contrato).

Porém, a interface por si só, na maioria das linguagens, não garante que esse contrato seja cumprido.

Ele se propõe a resolver isso criando uma subclasse `CollectionContract<T>` que implementa a lógica de cumprimento do contrato:

```
public abstract class CollectionContract<T> : IList<T> {
    public void Add(T item){
        AddCore(item);
        this.count++;
    }
    public int Count {
        get { return this.count; }
    }
    protected abstract void AddCore(T item);

    private int count;

    ...
}
```

[Um dos comentários](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2004/10/24/api-design-myth-interface-as-contract/#comment-12153) argumenta que essa abordagem pode introduzir um *overhead* inaceitável em tempo de execução mesmo quando esse *overhead* é limitado a *builds* de *debug*:

> In computer science and software engineering, the terms and conditions
>   on a contract are typically referred to as pre- and post-conditions.
>   While abstract classes could be used to validate that these conditions
>   are satisfied through the use of the template-method pattern, this
>   approach can introduce unacceptable run-time overhead even when
>   limited to debug builds.

Ele também fala que, em linguagens sem herança múltipla, como C# (e Java), essa abordagem impacta profundamente o design das classes. Mais ainda, a lógica de cumprimento do contrato está fazendo suposições que tornam a subclasse rígida e inflexível (como assumir que o contador deve ser guardado em um campo privado, e que esse campo deve ser do tipo inteiro).

Finalmente, propõe que o cumprimento do contrato seja garantido por meio de testes unitários realizados sobre as classes que implementam a interface (apesar que isso não é uma solução ideal, pois é externa ao contrato e à linguagem).

Minhas perguntas são:

- A que tipo de situação o comentarista se refere quando fala em *overhead* em tempo de execução?
- Essas situações em que o *overhead* ocorre são via de regra difíceis ou fáceis de prever? (para fins de ajudar a decidir quando é viável adotar a solução do artigo)
- Aliás, me responda diretamente: é sempre incorreto tentar garantir um contrato à maneira do artigo?
- Mesmo nas linguagens que permitem herança múltipla?

(Para quem se interessar pelo contexto do assunto, eu cheguei a esse artigo sobre interfaces partindo [deste aqui](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/12/02/the-case-against-interfaces-in-tdd/) e passando por [este outro](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/Interfacesarenotabstractions/). E [este aqui](https://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/11/02/back-to-basics-what-is-an-interface/) também é interessante).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Garantir que um contrato seja cumprido é um conceito desejável mas nem sempre viável. Pois em primeiro lugar é preciso *expressar* os termos do contrato em lógica, depois é preciso *provar* que a lógica desejada foi implementada. E essa "prova", quando possível, causa no mínimo um tempo maior de compilação, no máximo exige que checagens sejam feitas constantemente em tempo de execução. E, é claro, aumenta a quantidade de código sujeito a bugs (pois a declaração do contrato em si também é código, e também está sujeita a erros).

Nesse exemplo acima não há muito *overhead*, pois raramente alguém implementaria uma lista sem um campo auxiliar para armazenar a contagem. Mas quem deixou o comentário está certo ao dizer que isso restringe o uso da interface:

- Se quem implementou quiser acrescentar outros métodos de alterar a lista, mas não tem acesso [de escrita] ao campo `count` - já que é privado - como fazer? Seria necessário chamar um dos métodos dessa classe abstrata, que por sua vez chamaria de novo um método da classe concreta, que por fim faria o serviço. Esses redirecionamentos trariam sim um *overhead* desnecessário.
- Outra possibilidade seria *não existir* um método na classe abstrata que fizesse o que se quer. Por exemplo, se a implementação da lista for uma lista encadeada (ou mesmo uma árvore), e você quer um método que coloque um novo elemento mantendo a ordenação, como fazer isso de forma eficiente? Se você pudesse implementar você mesmo - com um cursor - e no final atualizar a contagem manualmente, blz, mas sem esse acesso você fica dependente de ter um método na classe abstrata que atenda a suas necessidades.
- Se você quiser uma lista *thread-safe*, terá que de alguma forma tornar *atômica* a operação de "acrescenta um elemento e incrementa a contagem". Se a implementação que já veio pronta não é atômica, isso reduz suas opções para implementar essa atomicidade de forma eficiente.
- O contrato diz que ao acrescentar um elemento a contagem tem necessariamente que aumentar? E se o elemento não puder ser inserido na lista, por qualquer motivo (por exemplo, se a lista não aceitar elementos repetidos, e o que estiver sendo adicionado já estiver na lista)? Pelo que li na documentação do [`IList.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ilist.add(v=vs.110).aspx), essa é uma possibilidade, e ao tentar "impor" o contrato dessa maneira a implementação restringe ainda mais os tipos de lista que podem ser criados, mais do que o contrato exige.

Esses são apenas alguns exemplos. Via de regra, é difícil responder no abstrato se "é sempre incorreto" ou não fazer isso, mas minha suspeita é que sim. Pois se algo está muito bem definido a ponto de não dar margem pra variações, isso não deveria sequer ser um contrato - e sim uma implementação concreta. Se a interface existe como algo abstrato, é porque se previu que pode ser necessário implementá-la de maneiras radicalmente diferentes. Ao restringir a implementação se coloca mais "barreiras" que o programador terá que transpor ao tentar fazer algo diferente do que foi previsto a princípio.

P.S. Alguns contratos podem sim ser garantidos, e não há mal nenhum em fazê-lo (embora não seja obrigatório). Um bom exemplo é o próprio sistema de tipos: as linguagens com tipagem estática obrigam o programador a só combinar variáveis, valores, métodos, classes, se todas tiverem o "tipo" correto, e o programa não compila se isso não puder ser verificado e provado. Já aquelas com tipagem dinâmica não fazem isso durante a compilação, mas acabam por ter certo *overhead* em tempo de execução. Esse seria um contra-exemplo, onde a garantia dos contratos [em princípio pelo menos] *reduz* o overhead em vez de aumentá-lo.

Comment: Uma coisa que me ocorreu: quando ele fala em overhead em builds de debug, ele está se referindo a _assertions_, como as do Java? Porque de outra forma não entendo como possa ser provada a implementação de um contrato em tempo de execução nesse tipo de linguagem. Mas de resto tudo faz muito sentido, se ninguém tiver nada a acrescentar vou acabar aceitando a resposta.

Comment: @Piovezan Eu não sei exatamente do que ele está falando, mas entendi de forma parecida com você. Existem muitas formas de compilação condicional - por exemplo ao fazer `if` com uma constante falsa, muitos compiladores não geram o código, sabendo que nunca será executado. Isso permite criar um build de debug (colocando a constante como verdadeira), com todas as verificações, mas na hora de colocar em produção o código roda no "modo burro" - sem verificar nem provar nada, como você reparou. P.S. sugiro aguardar mais antes de aceitar, esse tipo de pergunta costuma gerar respostas interessantes.